# How do I view the compiler output?

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

By clicking `View > Tool Windows > Messages`, I can see the build output messages from the IDE, but I don't see the raw compiler output or warnings. Is there a way I can enable the compiler messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLion delegates build work to CMake. To see CMake's internal log, add to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```